# Java programming architecture - Interface and implemented class should be in same package?

Tags: java, architecture, package

I really wonder that put an Interface and a (Implemented) class in same package or separate is better. I usually put them in same package since I believe it is more convenient to compare.

But couple of days ago, I had an opportunity to use apache `GenericObjectPool`. Then I found such a package structure like `org.apache.commons.pool.impl`.

After all, my question is when should I use former one and when should I use the other. Thanks for your sincere answers in advanced:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use interfaces just to lower the coupling, you can put interface and implementation into the same package. If you primarily count with more implementations if the interfaces, you should put them in separate package. This really depends on your design and I don't think there is a strict rule. Generally you should design you application as simple as possible and do the refactoring later. So when you start, you can put the implementation into the same package and only when it seems to be needed, you should split it.

Comment: Thanks Michal. It is nice that hear variety opinions. Simple is the best!

Comment: I got an additional Question, if I add an abstract Class, where it should be? put it with implements classes or interfaces?

Comment: As always, there is no dogma, but usually when I create an abstract class, then I have more descendants. In that case if every descendant is in different package, then I also put the abstract class in different package. If all descendants are in the same package, then I put them in same package. Let me give you an example (next post)

Comment: (...continue) If you have a package with geometrical shapes that have common functionality in one abstract class, it is no problem to keep all of them in one package. But imagine, that you have a large system and you want to configure some parts of it by a content in a database. Then a common functionality in abstract class will be in very different package then where the descendants are. Again, keep it simple. If it is logical to keep the abstract class in a different package, do it. But if you are not sure, keep all classes in one package.

Answer (score 2):

One of the tenets of composition is that interfaces are separated from their implementation.

Therefore it doesn't make much sense to constrain interfaces and their implementations to the same package.

(On a system I work on the interfaces are placed in a common area - loosely based on a concept of an *interface repository*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, is there more specific reasons why I should not put them in together? For instance, that makes easier to refactoring. Because I totally agree with what you wrote but somehow I feel the opposite way feels more comfortable to manage source code(maybe the reason why I felt is eclipse project explorer shows in that way. if put them in same package list looks shorter).

Answer (score 0):

If you define the responsibility of a package by its interfaces and classes, you attempt to abstract from concrete implementations. Hence, your package should consist of public types only.

If you continue to provide a default implementation for your package, I do not see any reason why not to put them into the same package. But I would always suggest to put your implementation into a separate project or more specific, to provide the `API` of your package and the implementation as two different artifacts (for example, jar-files).

Doing things this way, you support the following important aspects of abstraction:

- replacement of one implementation with another
- ensuring that client code depends only one the API and not the implementation (by adding only the API artifact to the clients classpath)

Comment: Thanks. now I see why apache makes their packages in that way